# Send whatsapp message using android/IOS aplication

Tags: javascript, android, html, api, whatsapp

What is the best way to open the WhatsApp application to send a message?

I wrote this code because I want it to open in one way through the computer browser, and otherwise by the mobile application.

First I made a condition to check where the user is accessing. If it is by some mobile device, it falls in the first condition, otherwise, it falls on the second link.

The condition of opening the application is not working, I think it may be the 'whatsapp: // ...' link can anyone help me?

```
        function MakeLink() {
            if ( isMobile.any ) {
                let target = 'whatsapp://send?'
                    target += 'phone='+ encodeURIComponent(phone);
                return target
            } else {
                let target = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?'
                    target += 'phone='+ phone;
                return target
            }

        }

    window.location.href = MakeLink();
```

Ps: I do not want to use the 'api.whatsapp' address because it drops to an intermediate page, increasing the client path.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is another way without api

```
let target = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?'
  target += 'phone='+ phone;
```

EDIT: it suddenly stopped working since yesterday.

Comment: Yeah, I solved the problem using web.whatsapp.com/send for browser, and api.whatsapp.com for mobile devices.

And yes, whatsapp's "api" has been experiencing problems in the past few days, and no one knows why.

Thank you man.